# Does nearSphere use a 2dsphere index with legacy coordinate pairs?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nearsphere

A mongodb query uses a location field and multiple other fields:

```
{
    "location": {
        "$nearSphere": ["<val>"],
        "$maxDistance": "<val>"
    },
    "userId": {
        "$nin": ["<vals>"]
    },
    "date": {
        "$gte": "<val>"
    },    
    "age": {
        "$in": ["<vals>"]
    },
    "property1": {
        "$in": ["<vals>"]
    },
    "weight": {
        "$in": ["<vals>"]
    }
}
```

The location field uses [legacy coordinates pairs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-legacy).

A `2dsphere` index is created in order to use multiple fields.

> Unlike a compound 2d index which can reference one location field and
>   one other field, a compound 2dsphere index can reference multiple
>   location and non-location fields.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "height": 1,
    "weight": 1,
    "age": 1,
    "date": -1,
    "location": "2dsphere",
    "userId": 1
}
```

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere) say:

> $nearSphere requires a geospatial index:
>
> - 2dsphere index for location data defined as GeoJSON points
> - 2d index
>     for location data defined as legacy coordinate pairs. To use a 2d
>     index on GeoJSON points, create the index on the coordinates field of
>     the GeoJSON object.

And [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-indexed-field-restrictions):

> Fields with 2dsphere indexes must hold geometry data in the form of
>   coordinate pairs or GeoJSON data.

1) Will the index be used at all? From the docs I understand that a `2dsphere` index requires location data to be a `GeoJSON` object rather than legacy coordinates pairs. On the other hand a `2dsphere` index can be built also from legacy coordinate pairs.

2) Can the index (or query) be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to look/use $geoWithin instead of $nearSphere (if your usecase matches). $nearsphere sorts the result in increasing order of distance from the center point, while $within don't. If in your case you don't need sorting based on distance or you are sorting on any other field, than there is no point of using $nearsphere.

Also for $geoWithin, 2dsphere index is not mandatory, though needed for performance. So if, in your query if other match conditions leaves a very small set of results left to filtered out for location match, than index is not needed at all on location field. My point is to create an index on only those fields, which have very high cardinality, there is no point of adding all your fields in a compound index. Currently, you have 7 fields in your compound index.

1) Use mongo explain query to check whether the index is being used or not (and share execution plan here as well). The 2dsphere index supports data stored as GeoJSON objects and legacy coordinate pairs. For legacy coordinate pairs, the index converts the data to GeoJSON Point.

2) For index optimization, removes fields from the index with low cardinality. Order of field in a compound index matters, so sort them on the same fact. I don't think (can't comment much as I don't know the use case), there is any room for improvement in the query. Also, you can remove userId from the index, $nin don't work that good with compound index.

P.S.: Cardinality: number of elements of the set. Eg. a field "Gender" can have only two fields "M" and "F", thus very low cardinality. While a field "Mobile" has very distinct numbers hence very high cardinality. If you are using 2dsphere index in compound index, use it at first place.

Try different compound indexes with atmost 3-fields.